# Format bound double property in MudBlazor textfield

Tags: format, blazor, textfield, mudblazor

I have a model with double values which is bound to MudTextfield in this way:

```html
<MudTextField @bind-Value="product.Price" Label="Price"/>

@code {
  Product product = new Product { Name="Test-Abo", Price=199.12345 }
}
```

MudTextfield converts double to string and when string is edited it converts back to double, so that is working fine. But I have two problems:

1. In my culture, the decimal point is written as a comma so the textfield shows a comma but I want to have a decimal dot like in C#.
2. I want the text field to truncate the decimals to two even if the value in the model has more

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a [MudTextField](https://mudblazor.com/components/textfield) there are a few options to convert the value of type `T` (in your case `double`) to `string`:

You can either use:
`Culture` ... to override the default UI Culture
`Format` ... to override the ToString() format
These will actually configure the default converter

Or:
`Converter` ... to override the default converter with a custom converter with your own conversion funcs between T and string and vice-versa.

To solve your problem, set the `Culture` to `Invariant` which will always use the dot (.) as a decimal separator and set the `Format` to `"F2"` which will truncate your floating point value to two decimals:

```html
<MudTextField @bind-Value="product.Price" Label="Price" Format="F2" 
              Culture="@CultureInfo.InvariantCulture"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation. Works like a charm!

Comment: Is there a way to use both ',' and '.' as a decimal separator?

Comment: @mihnea2kx Yes, you can implement a custom converter, see an example at  https://mudblazor.com/features/converters#custom-binding-converters